# Save an array of ActiveRecords objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to save an array of ActiveRecords in my controller, but this error is showing up:

> undefined method 'save' for #`<Array:...>`

I have this method of model:

```
def self.import(file)
  reservations = []
  CSV.foreach(file, headers: true ) do |row|
    room_id = Classroom.where(code: row[0]).pluck(:id).first
    row[0] = room_id
    reservations << Reservation.new(number_of_guests: row[1], check_in_date: row[2], check_out_date: row[3], room_id: row[0])
  end
  reservations
end
```

And I have this following controller:

```
def create_import
  @reservations = Reservation.import(params[:file].path)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @reservations.save
      format.html { redirect_to @reservation, notice: 'Reservations was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @reservation }
    else
      format.html { render :import }
      format.json { render json: @reservations.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

How can I do this save method? I want to show a report with errors in my view.

Comment: Should `Classroom.where(code: row[0]).pluck(:id)` be `Classroom.where(code: row[0]).pluck(:id).first`???  The first one will give you the `room_id` wrapped in an array.

Comment: @br3nt yeah, fixed. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you should call `save` method on each of them:

```
@reservations.each(&:save)
```

Or install some third party gem that provides a multiple `insert` feature. You should also rewrite your `if` statement, since the expression above will always return the collection itself, thus evaluating to `true`.

Comment: So if I use this method, how can I return all the errors to my view?

Comment: @gumaro: you can use `reject` or `select` instead of `each` to collect instances that failed or succeeded to be saved.

Comment: `records_with_errors = @reservations.reject {|r| r.save }`

Comment: @br3nt thanks.
But I'm trying to understand where I have to place this code and how I call the errors in my view.

I'm sorry if I'm asking too much :/

Comment: This is all in the `create_import` action.  So, your success condition where all reservations are successfully imported is if there are no records with errors.  That happens when `reservations_with_errors.empty?` returns `true`.  If you want to check if there are errors, you can use `reservations_with_errors.any?` instead.

Comment: @br3nt Thanks. 
If I want to show the successfully imported and the records with errors?

Comment: @gumaro: then you can use `partition` method instead of `select`/`reject`, which should give your two collections, the one that has proceeded to the db, and the one that has failed `save` method.